# How to follow Pyramid redirect on tests?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pyramid

I have a view which returns like:

```
headers = remember(request, str(user.id))
return HTTPFound(location=request.route_url('home'), headers=headers)
```

and I'm writing a test but how do I follow the redirect from the code above? I still get the HTTPFound object and also its response.request which is supposed to be the request which initiated the response is giving me None.

Here's what my test code looks so far:

```
request = testing.DummyRequest(
    post=MultiDict(email='me@gmail.com', password='random'))
response = login(request)
```

here, response is the HTTPFound but how do I follow the redirect to home?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realize that this isn't using `DummyRequest`

I would recommend functional testing because `WebTest` makes it easier to do, and managing.

On the response that returns a redirect you can call `follow` to follow the full request.

http://webtest.pythonpaste.org/en/latest/index.html

```
redirect_response = self.testapp.post(
    '/signup', params=post_params, status=302)
full_response = redirect_response.follow()
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured this would be the closest thing. But the thing about this is that the response is now an HTML string right? I mean, if the view returns a dict with some objects in it and I wanna check it which attribute of response are they stored?

Comment: It would be great to have the rendered response + the actual dict returned by the views.